# FTP upload File error with Ftplib in the python

Tags: python, ftplib

I use ftplib, but can not upload files to the server. Two methods do not to work

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.encoding = 'utf-8'
try:
    ftp.connect(host, port)
    ftp.login(username, password)
    print(ftp.getwelcome())
except(socket.error, socket.gaierror):  # ftp error
    print("ERROR: cannot connect [{}:{}]".format(host, port))
except ftplib.error_perm:  # user Authentication failed
    print("ERROR: user Authentication failed ")

filename = 'readme'

# Method 1
try:
    with open("readme.txt", 'rb') as fp:
        res = ftp.storlines("STOR " + filename, fp)
        if not res.startswith('226 Transfer complete'):
            print('Upload failed')

except ftplib.all_errors as e:
    print('FTP error:', e)

# Method 2
try:
    bufsize = 1024
    fp = open("readme.txt", 'rb')
    res = ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + "readme", fp, bufsize)  # 上传文件
    if res.find('226') != -1:
        print('upload file complete', "readme")
except ftplib.all_errors as e:
    print('FTP error:', e)
```

Login success

'''
*welcome* '220 Microsoft FTP Service'
220 Microsoft FTP Service
'''

But when upload file, it return error

'''
*get* '220 Microsoft FTP Service\n'

*resp* '220 Microsoft FTP Service'
*cmd* 'USER ftp'

*put* 'USER ftp\r\n'

*get* '331 Password required\n'

*resp* '331 Password required'

*cmd* 'PASS *******'

*put* 'PASS *******\r\n'

*get* '230 User logged in.\n'

*resp* '230 User logged in.'

*welcome* '220 Microsoft FTP Service'

220 Microsoft FTP Service

*cmd* 'TYPE A'

*put* 'TYPE A\r\n'

*get* '200 Type set to A.\n'

*resp* '200 Type set to A.'

*cmd* 'PASV'

*put* 'PASV\r\n'

*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (172,18,196,55,208,114).\n'

*reFTP error: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respondsp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (172,18,196,55,208,114).'

'''

Comment: The error message sounds like a port number is blocked. Have you tried increasing the debug level? Perhaps that would reveal some useful diagnostics.

Comment: I have added the debug level.

Comment: Try disabling passive mode?

Comment: Thanks, you save me. I add "ftp.af = socket.AF_INET6" it works.

Comment: Uh, that's not passive mode at all, it's IPv6.

Comment: How can I disabing passive mode?

Comment: It's probably not important if you got it to work by switching to IPv6; usually people actually have the opposite problem (active mode requires the server to contact the client, which many modern firewalls prohibit).

Comment: anyway, thank u very much.